# XamlParseException occured. Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am new to MVVM , I have got some commands working. My application was working fine. Suddenly, I have this crazy xaml exception which I tried to resolve looking at already available answers on StackOverflow. I was not able to . If I drop the interaction.triggers tag the window opens fine, else I have the error as mentioned in the title. Please provide your inputs. Thanks.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:Test.Framework.Converter"
    xmlns:me="clr-namespace:Test"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Test.View"  
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Title="Testing Windows" Height="367" Width="620"   Icon="/Test;component/Resources/AppIcon.ico"   WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Initialized">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  StartInitializingCmd, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  LoadFeatureListCmd, Mode=OneWay}"  />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  ClosedCmd, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding  ClosingCmd, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding   WindowKeyUpCmd, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 public MainViewModel()
    {


        StartInitializingCmd = new RelayCommand(() => StartInitializing(), () => true);

        fl = new ObservableCollection<Feature>();
        fl.CollectionChanged += new   NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(fl_CollectionChanged);

        WindowKeyUpCmd = new KeyBoardCommand(new Action<object, KeyEventArgs>(Window_KeyUp));
        ClosedCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Closed(), () => true);
        ClosingCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Closing(), () => true);
        LoadFeatureListCmd = new RelayCommand(() => StartLoading(), () => true);
    }
```

Comment: Digged in to find the stackTrace.

Comment: at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)